# Normalizing specific model payload on Ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, serialization

I'm trying to request a JSON structure that is not common for the Ember default adapter. The response does not have the root key. Here's what I mean:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Dude'
    fullName: 'Nice Dude'
  },
  { 
    name: 'Foo'
    fullName: 'Foo Bar'
  }
]
```

So, let's say that this is the response for `GET /users`.

I can workaround and successfully `resolve` this writing this boilerplate:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizePayload: function(payload) {
    return { user: payload };
  }
});
```

But this is totally wrong, cause i'm overwriting all payload responses. Which would be the clean way of normalizing only `GET /users` payload?

Comment: I believe you're after `normalizeResponse` - override the method inside `app/serializers/user.js` - http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeResponse - you can create a root hash and insert your payload inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to override [`normalizeFindAllResponse`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeFindAllResponse).